# Delete specific subdirectory file(s)?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I require a batch script that will delete a specifically named file or list of files in a defined subdirectory. The subdirectory structure will always be the same however the root folder of the .bat will probably not be.

A script for this would be /fantastic/. Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us what you've already tried? SuperUser is a place where we try to help those who themselves have tried to resolve something, but get stuck or run into a problem. You improve your chances of getting a response if you provide details of what you've already tried. This does two things: 1) lets us know you are willing to put in an effort and not expect someone else to just do it for you, and 2) helps us to not suggest what you've already tried

Comment: I previously made an effort with Python however, despite it working, the difficulty in packing it up for Windows was a nightmare. I know a little but not nearly enough about scripts to do it myself, so yes, this is something of a leech, but in good spirits.

Comment: For a start, you could [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/726150/edit) & include your Python script.

Comment: Derp, my mistake. The Python script I made was for something different but related to the same project. Bad start? haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried just using `del /s <filename>`?  That should delete matching filename in subdirectories.  You could script it, but probably don't need to..

Comment: That's actually exactly what I needed, thank you!

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help...